# In workbench how to retrieve the work item result in a task in business process?

Tags: drools, jbpm

In my business process I have two tasks which are custom work items. 
The input data of the second work item is the output of the first one.

In my first work item I have put the result(an hashmap) in to the completeWorkItem method.

```
Msc8007Response ret = this.consumeService();    
Map<String,Object> result = new HashMap<String,Object>();
result.put("qianhaiAddrResp", ret);
manager.completeWorkItem(workItem.getId(), result);
```

The "qianhaiAddrResp" is what required in the second task. How can I retrieve it in the second task "Baidu Addr Work item"?

[image]

Also, The "process variable" and "condition" in the XOR gateway are empty. The XOR is a checking point right after a work item for some conditional checking based on the previous work item's result. Can any one give some hints ?
[image]

Comment: One option would be to pass it as a parameter to the second custom work item. Did you try that?

Comment: @PrasanthNair I don't find anywhere in the business process panel can pass data as parameter. Could you please advise ?

Comment: You can get the value of variable 'result' using kcontext.getVariable() method.

Comment: @PrasanthNair I did try using the kcontext.getVariable(key) method to get the object in the map which is the result of the first work item. But the return value is null, even for a simple string test.